# how can i share a layout in nested routes in next 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have this folder structure in Next 13

```
app
  -categories
    -(category)
      -edit
      -new
      **layout.txs**
  -subcategories
    -(subcategory)
      -edit
      -new
      **layout.txs**
```

The layout has the same structure for both folders, how can I share it between both folders so as not to duplicate code?

I tried to include the two main folders in a group but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

From:

```
app
  -categories
    -(category)
      -edit
      -new
      **layout.txs**
  -subcategories
    -(subcategory)
      -edit
      -new
      **layout.txs**
```

to

```
app
  -(group)
    **layout.txs**
    -categories
      -(category)
        -edit
        -new
    -subcategories
      -(subcategory)
        -edit
        -new
```